# Map plot in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, choropleth

Suppose i have the following dataframe in python :

| Country | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Arizona | 10 |
| Los Angeles | 20 |
| Alaska | 6 |
| Huawai | NA |

First i want to bucket the values based on a range for example every 5, 0-5,5-10..

I want to make a map plot with plotly that has a discerte legend (the Bucket) and the color to be as the Value. Moreover in case the value is na i want to be plotted but with a different color, lets say black.

I've managed to make the plot but without the above constrains. Finally i want your opinion regarding the Bucket column. Below is the code that i wrote, is there any better way to write it?

```
`def Bucket(row):
if row['GDP'] >10:
    return '>10'
if row['GDP'] >20  and row['GDP'] < 10:
    return '10-20'
if row['GDP'] > 20 and row['GDP'] < 30:
    return '20-30'
if row['GDP']=="NA":
    return "NA"
```

Thank you!

Curently my code for the plot is:

```
`fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=counties, locations='county', 
                color='GDP',
                color_discrete_map =[[0, 'rgb(240,240,240)'],
                  [10, 'rgb(13,136,198)'],
                  [20, 'rgb(191,247,202)'],
                  [30, 'rgb(4,145,32)'],],
                category_orders={
                  'category' : [
                      '>10',
                      '10-20',
                      '20-30']},
                color_continuous_midpoint=2,
                range_color=[0,1],
                scope="usa",
                hover_name = 'county_name'
                )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your bucket column, you could more easily do this:

```
df['bucket'] = pd.cut(df['GDP'], [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25], labels=['<5', '5-10', '10-15', '15-20', '20-25'])
```

However, if you wanted to keep a colorscale you would have to use a numeric value rather than a string (as now is in the bucket column). Instead, leave the color based on GDP and define the steps like this:

```
colors = np.repeat(plotly.colors.n_colors('rgb(240,240,240)', 'rgb(4,145,32)', 4, colortype='rgb'), 2)

steps = [0]+[0.25]*2+[0.5]*2+[0.75]*2+[1]

scale = [[steps[n], colors[n]] for n in range(8)]


fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=counties, locations='county', 
            color='GDP',
            color_continuous_scale=scale,
            scope="usa",
            hover_name = 'county_name'
            )
```